# Batch: For-Loop break up after finding 'NUL'

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem evaluating a .txt file.
Inside my approach I iterate to each line inside the file, however at some point the FOR loop is left:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in (textfile.txt) do (echo %%G)
```

When evaluating the .txt file I find out something unnormal at one line:

[image]

The `NUL` is only shown using Notepadd++, not when viewig in normal editor. What does this mean? In the normal editor the `NUL`s are simply white spaces.
I sadly cannot modify the source-textfile.

Does anybody know how I can prevent the For-Loop to break up at this specific line?
Only 10% of the textfile is evaulated because of this.

Comment: A plain text file does not contain null bytes, except it is UTF-16 encoded. Your text file looks like being partly ASCII/ANSI/OEM encoded with one byte per character and partly UTF-16 encoded with two or in rare cases four bytes per character. Windows command processor interprets a text file as ASCII/ANSI/OEM encoded file with null byte being interpreted as end of string.

Comment: Have you tried it using `@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "textfile.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %%G`?

Comment: Ah okay thanks at all I finally managed if to read in the complete file and then replace all '\x00 character :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) treats Null characters/bytes like line-breaks, which can be used to remove the Nulls.

The following script assumes that there is no line with just a single character, which result from the said Null-to-line-break conversion, in which case the affected lines become concatenated:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Reset line collection buffer:
set "COLL="
rem /* Iterate through lines of text file, while Nulls are treated
rem    like line-breaks: */
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%G in ('^< "textfile.txt" find /V ""') do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%G"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check whether current line consists of a single character:
    if "!LINE:~1!"=="" (
        rem /* There is just a single character, hence put it
        rem    in a buffer and do not output anything yet;
        rem    the `for /F` loop transports the
        rem    resulting string beyond `endlocal`: */
        for /F "delims=" %%E in (^""!COLL!!LINE!"^") do (
            endlocal
            set "COLL=%%~E"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    ) else (
        rem /* There are more characters, hence
        rem    return the resulting string, if any: */
        if defined COLL (
            echo(!COLL!
            endlocal
            set "COLL="
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        rem // Return the current line:
        echo(!LINE!
    )
    endlocal
)
rem // Deplete remaining buffer:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined COLL echo(!COLL!
endlocal
```